# Is it possible to create a virtual IOHIDDevice from userspace?

Tags: macos, hid, iokit

I have an HID device that is somewhat unfortunately designed (the Griffin Powermate) in that as you turn it, the *input value* for the "Rotation Axis" HID element doesn't change unless the speed of rotation dramatically changes or unless the direction changes. It sends many *HID reports* (angular resolution appears to be about 4deg, in that I get ~90 reports per revolution - not great, but whatever...), but they all report the same value (generally -1 or 1 for CCW and CW respectively -- if you turn faster, it will report -2 & 2, and so on, but you have to turn *much* faster.  As a result of this unfortunate behavior, I'm finding this thing largely useless.

It occurred to me that I might be able to write a background userspace app that seized the physical device and presented another, virtual device with some minor additions so as to cause an input value change for every report (like a wrap-around accumulator, which the HID spec has support for -- God only knows why Griffin didn't do this themselves.)

But I'm not seeing how one would go about creating the kernel side object for the virtual device from userspace, and I'm starting to think it might not be possible. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894509/macos-virtual-input-devices), and its indications are not good, but it's low on details.

Alternately, if there's a way for me to spoof reports on the existing device, I suppose that would do it as well, since I could set it back to zero immediately after it reports -1 or 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can simulate input events via [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) but this might not suffice for your purposes, as that's mainly designed for simulating keyboard and mouse events.

Second, the HID driver family of the IOKit framework contains a user client on the (global) `IOHIDResource` service, called `IOHIDResourceDeviceUserClient`. It appears that this can spawn `IOHIDUserDevice` instances on command from user space. In particular, the userspace IOKitLib contains a `IOHIDUserDeviceCreate` function which seems to be supposed to be able to do this. The HID family source code even comes with a little [demo of this which creates a virtual keyboard](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-503.1.13/tools/IOHIDUserDeviceTest.c) of sorts. Unfortunately, although I can get this to build, it fails on the `IOHIDUserDeviceCreate` call. (I can see in IORegistryExplorer that the `IOHIDResourceDeviceUserClient` instance is never created.) I've not investigated this further due to lack of time, but it seems worth pursuing if you need its functionality.